# Module 'mpi4py' has no attribute 'MPI'

Tags: python, anaconda, mpi, conda, mpi4py

I wanted to install mpi4py from pip so that I can use petsc4py. However, the installation is not running where I am getting error "*module 'mpi4py' has no attribute 'MPI'*".

The test code is as below:

```
import mpi4py


comm = mpi4py.MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
print('My rank is ',rank)
```

Based on my google search I have installed MS-MPI latest version (v10) and included the Bin folder in the PATH in environmental variables. That is not resolving the issue. I am running the program in Spyder IDE.

mpi4py Version 3.0.3.

Comment: fwiw, the `mpi4py` doc uses the following syntax `from mpi4py import MPI` and then `comm=MPI.COMM_WORLD`

Comment: Gilles Gouaillardet's comment solved the issue.

Comment: This is just how Python imports work. Importing a package does not automatically import all of its sub packages.